# Javascript remove item on array using splice() not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an **array** like this `var arr = [foo1:"bar1", foo2:"bar", foo3:"bar3"]`.

Then I used this `arr.splice(index, 1);` given that the `index` is dynamic lets just say it's `0` but the value `foo1:"bar1"` wasn't removed from the **array**.

Also the above **array** works on my code but it shows an error on JSFiddle. I have no idea why.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I dont know why it doesn't show an error on my console but here's how I did it.

var arr = [];

I dynamically added value to the array by doing

```
arr["foo"] = "bar";
```

which resulted to `[foo:"bar"];`

Any idea guys?

**EDIT 2**

Here's the screenshot of the console. 
[image]

Comment: That doesn't look right... You have an array or an object?

Comment: That isn't a valid array. We can't help without some valid structure

Comment: This will give you an error.If you want to create a JSON array you should write like `var arr = [{foo1:"bar1"},{ foo2:"bar"}, {foo3:"bar3"}];`

Comment: Your array is not an valid array then how come `Also the above array works on my code` ?

Comment: This is more of an object structure (if you replace square brackets with curly braces), rather than array. if you try to instantiate var arr = [foo1:"bar1", foo2:"bar", foo3:"bar3"], it will give you an error.

Comment: You are turning your initial array into an object...javascript doesn't have associative arrays. `arr["foo"] = "bar";` will essentially become `{foo:'bar'}`

Comment: @charlietfl but why did the console printed `[ ]` square brackets instead of the curly one? See edit with screen shot.

Comment: From the screen shot, it looks like it's an array with custom properties that are not themselves array elements so you can't `.slice()` them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure of this array is not valid.

```
var arr = [foo1:"bar1", foo2:"bar", foo3:"bar3"];
```

An array will have comma-separated items within square braces `[]`, not key values

If you want to have key values, then it should be Object with curly braces `{}`

```
var arr = {foo1:"bar1", foo2:"bar", foo3:"bar3"};
```

and if you want to remove first property from the `arr`, then do

```
var keys = Object.keys( arr );
delete arr[ keys[ 0 ] ];
```

For adding a key value,

```
arr[ "foo5" ] = "bar";
```

Comment: there really is no reliable `first` since objects have no order

Comment: @charlietfl it will have no defined order if the object is constructed at runtime. if the object is defined at compile time, then the defined order will be maintained. try `var arr = {foo4:"bar1", foo2:"bar", foo3:"bar3"};` and then `delete arr[ Object.keys( arr )[ 0 ] ]`

Comment: But how do I dynamically add a key:value pair on that format in an object?

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx `arr[ "foo5" ] = "bar";` should add or overwrite `foo5` property into `arr`

Comment: Thanks man. This helped me a lot. The only thing that got me stuck is that the console seems to accept that array as valid. I got confused.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Long way:

```
var arr = [];

var foo1 = {};
foo1['foo1'] = 'bar1';

var foo2 = {};
foo1['foo2'] = 'bar2';

arr.push(foo1);
arr.push(foo2);

alert(arr.length); // output: 2

var index = arr.indexOf(arr, foo1); // or var index = $.inArray(arr, foo1);
arr.splice(index, 1);

alert(arr.length) // output: 1
```

Comment: how did jQuery get into this?

Comment: Thanks Happy but this seems to be not dynamic.